# How to manage AWS Loadbalancer Controller on OpenShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, amazon-elb

I have a question about setting up a network loadbalancer with the annotation service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip to redirect UDP traffic directly to the Pods, I installed the AWSLoadBalancerController via the openshift console
the Targetgroupbindings are created automatically.
[image]

the problem I have is that no target is created in these target groups (on AWS console)

[image]

The error fron the aws loadbalancer controller:

```
"level":"error","ts":1667487109.8040307,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.targetGroupBinding","msg":"Reconciler error","reconciler group":"elbv2.k8s.aws","reconcile │
```

│ r kind":"TargetGroupBinding","name":"k8s-titan-titan-999b29c596","namespace":"titanlive","error":"cannot resolve pod ENI for pods: [titan/titan-stream-connect-runner │
│ -backup-596bdd6cc5-ngnds]"

environment: Openshift 4.11 installed via openshift-installer

Thank You

Installed AWS Load Balancer Operator on a didicated namespace,

Comment: More information around what you installed, what your config looks like, what the service type is please.

Comment: Hello @Kris.J, I reatched Redhat support and was told that the AWS Loadbalancer controllet with the following type is not supported: 

annotation: aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Openshift does offer a LoadBalancer Controller for AWS, but it does not support IP Mode. RedHat team confirmed that for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34325693)